# Unknown KieSession name in drools 6.0 (while trying to add drools to existing maven/eclipse project)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, drools

I am trying to adapt drools6.0 for an existing code base (it is maven project under eclipse).
I didnt had need to learn drools or maven before (though they were part of my previous project), suffice to say I am lost in what I wanted to do.
Based on my understanding (googling), java class files get hooked to rules based on the package name(?). That takes care of compile time issues. But I am seeing null pointer exception at run time. Inorder to adapt drools into my existing code base: I  1)created helloworld drools project, ran it successfully 2)copied the java file to my existing package, 3)created rule file in Eclipse with correct package: FIle->New->other->Rule Resource; 3)converted existing project into drools package by right clicking project and configure->convert to drools project

This all takes care of compilation issues, but I get following run time error

```
[main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession    name: ksession-rules
java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.java.com.harmonia.cbm.afloat.dataaquisition.dql.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:23)
```

This is because ksession that is returned from kcontainer is null and throws null pointer exception in last line

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
// above line is returning null
Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("Hello World");
message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
kSession.insert(message);
```

Already spent more than a day trying to figure out how drools works and how above can be fixed. Pl suggest

1) am I taking the right approach to convert existing project into drools project. I want all  existing functionality of my code base; but want to add rules based approach for future enhancements. Came across following link, but not clear if it helps my situation
http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Retrofitting-a-project-with-JBoss-Rules-td48656.html

2)Any useful drools tutorials in better understanding following 3 lines (besides java docs)

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
```

3)Any hints on resolving null pointer exception (assuming I am taking the right and easy approach of converting existing project into drools project)

**UPDATE**
@David: thanks for detailed post. I realized that converting existing project into maven project, while works, did not appeal to me since existing directory structure/naming is preserved (most likely different from what maven creates by default). I posted alternative solution where I thought this problem has to do with classpath issues http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Null-pointer-exception-when-adding-drools-to-existing-project-td4027944.html#a4028011

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit similar problems.

I think that part of the problem is trying to live in both worlds. The JBoss Drools eclipse plugin world and the maven world.

I have Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler) with various Jboss/Drools plugins installed.

I took a working eclipse example and made sure I could run it in maven.

1. Created a demo drools project  File->New->Other..->Drools->Drools Project
2. Ensured you could run the test programs DroolsTest
3. Converted project to maven project - Configure->Convert To Maven Project
   (This will create a pom.xml file with many dependencies. These can be prunes)
4. Removed the Drools Library from the build path - in the project properties Build Path -> Libraries - select Drools Library and click Remove
5. Disable the Drools builder - in project properties Builders -> uncheck Drools Builder
6. Comment out dependancy jsr94 from the pom.xml(not retrievable)
7. Run maven from the command line "mvm clean install".

This should give you a project that builds and runs entirely from Maven.

Add to your pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

And

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Try:

mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.sample.DroolsTest"

It should produce:

```
...
[com.sample.DroolsTest.main()] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject - Found kmodule: file:/Users/davidbernard/Projects/action-deducing-diff/xx/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
[com.sample.DroolsTest.main()] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added:FileKieModule[ ReleaseId=x:x:1.0file=/Users/davidbernard/Projects/action-deducing-diff/xx/target/classes]
[com.sample.DroolsTest.main()] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject - Found kmodule: file:/Users/davidbernard/Projects/action-deducing-diff/xx/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
[com.sample.DroolsTest.main()] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added:FileKieModule[ ReleaseId=x:x:1.0file=/Users/davidbernard/Projects/action-deducing-diff/xx/target/classes]
Hello World
Goodbye cruel world
...
```

You should now also be able to run DroolsTest from eclipse.

You will have a rules->Sample.drl file and a kmodule.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

The "ksession" name should match the code creating the ksession:

```
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
```

The "packages" should match the directory the rule file is in.

Comment: It is just the `src/main/resources/META-INF/kmodule.xml` file that you really need.  The other information can most likely be discovered from your top-level pom.xml file.

Comment: I am using drools 6.5.0 and I still have this issue, maven build and test works fine but when project is run in tomcat it complains about pom.properties file not being found, and I literally have to create one manually in src/main/resources/META-INF/maven

Answer (score 2):

**I think there is a much simpler answer** ... I stumbled upon this just today as I was attempting the very same thing and got it working after following a clue in the discussion lists:

I was Trying to get Drools to execute from Spring MVC WEB in Pure Maven Project (no added natures of any kind) and ran head first into this problem:

***ERROR KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: ksession-rules***

Initial RND: (some direction - but no solutions)

[Unknown KieSession name in drools 6.0 (while trying to add drools to existing maven/eclipse project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466716/unknown-kiesession-name-in-drools-6-0-while-trying-to-add-drools-to-existing-ma)
http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Null-pointer-exception-when-adding-drools-to-existing-project-td4027944.html#a4028011

Related Problem (... but a *big* clue):

WARN  ClasspathKieProject - Unable to load pom.properties tried recursing down from/Apache-Tomcat7/webapps/maven-spring-drools/WEB-INF/classes

SOLUTION:

As it turns out, creating the directory **WEB-INF/classes** and placing the files **pom.properties** and **pom.xml** in it solves the problem. The clue came from this link: **http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools-6-Unable-to-build-index-of-kmodule-xml-td4026791.html** - where Mark Proctor indicated that the project has to be a maven project, and it ***needs to find pom.properties***.

*As soon as the KIE finds the pom.properties file, it figures out the KieSession name and the problem is solved.*

Note: I'd suspect you'd have to manually keep that POM.XML file updated but the pom.properties file never changes.

This has been my experience - hope it helps someone....

Comment: pom.properties has version info, and it changes right?

Comment: What values do you put in the file?

Answer (score 2):

Little late on the answer here, but this might help others.

Check your META-INF/Maven/pom.properties file, and it might contain this:

```
groupId=
artifactId=
version=
```

Nothing was defined! Changed it to:

```
groupId=com.sample  (package name)
artifactId=DroolsTest (class name)
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Copy and paste the same data from pom.properties file to pom.xml . Runs fine now.

Answer (score 1):

We have a number of examples, all documented. that get you started. Each can be run from the command line with maven, and have  unit test to show them running.
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/master/drools-examples-api

Docs here:
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/KIEChapter.html#KIEExamplesSection

Comment: I infact looked at the docs and examples and could not reach to conclusion.

Comment: I infact looked at the docs and examples and could not reach to conclusion (because they are aimed at getting started and api details). None of them show how to convert an existing project into drools (there were bits and pieces there, which I believe I covered in my question). I did look at my project under properties->java build path ->libraries and I see drools library with almost 20 files there; so I am thinking the problem is not classpath related (may be related to directory structure or kmodule.xml is not linking the class files with rules file correctly). I am newbie to drools..

Comment: @david: thanks. Alternative solution is discussed at http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Null-pointer-exception-when-adding-drools-to-existing-project-td4027944.html#a4028011

Comment: Yes - well this problem very much still exists when trying to get Spring 3.2.X MVC working with Drools V6.0.0.Final KIE. The very same result 

ERROR KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: ksession-rules
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue while trying out the JBoss Examples at:
4.2.6.1. Default KieSession
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch04.html#KIEExamplesSection

I was getting the following exception on trying out the default KieSession example:

```
org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject - Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=file:/C:/Repo/Git/temp/drools-examples/drools-examples/drools-examples-service/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Repo/Git/temp/drools-examples/drools-examples/drools-examples-service/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 52; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'kmodule'.
10:29:18.243 [main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: testsession
```

I realised that the issue was due to the xmlns used in the default kiession example from Jboss Docs:
From JBoss Docs - HAS ISSUE:

```
kmodule xmlns="http://www.drools.org/xsd/kmodule"

</kmodule>
```

What I used - WORKS WITHOUT ISSUE:

```
kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"

</kmodule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I was trying to add the following maven dependency in pom.xml after removing those dependencies. it worked for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
        <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```