# Unable to build index of kmodule

Tags: java, maven, jboss, drools

I have been trying to include drools in one of the projects i have been working on. I have used a example internet to try drools with maven. the example project works fine but when i run the same example in my project(maven as well), it gives me the error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZIUZ.png)

```
<pre>
[main] INFO org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject - Found kmodule: file:/D:/Projects/VMS/MaluAPI/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
[main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.ClasspathKieProject - Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=file:/D:/Projects/VMS/MaluAPI/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Projects/VMS/MaluAPI/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 53; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'kmodule'.
[main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: ksession-rules
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:24)
</pre>
```

I have created the kmodule in the correct directory as well. 
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw8ME.png)

I have gone through some questions in stack overflow describing the same but i haven't still been able to get it working.

[Unknown KieSession name in drools 6.0 (while trying to add drools to existing maven/eclipse project)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466716/unknown-kiesession-name-in-drools-6-0-while-trying-to-add-drools-to-existing-ma/37929975#37929975)

I will add my kmodule here as well.

```
<pre>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
        <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
            <ksession name="ksession-rules"/>
        </kbase>
        <kbase name="dtables" packages="dtables">
            <ksession name="ksession-dtables"/>
        </kbase>
        <kbase name="process" packages="process">
            <ksession name="ksession-process"/>
        </kbase>
    </kmodule>
</pre>
```

Comment: I assume the <pre> tags in your code are not really present in you kmodule.xml file, right?

Comment: no sorry it just added when i put the code here

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <kbase name="helloKbase">
        <ksession name="helloKSession" default="true" />
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

I know it's a late reply, but I managed to get it working with this configuration. Maybe someone will find it helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't check if it works with this code but do you think the problem was?

Comment: I think you were missing the xmlns:xsi property for the kmodule